# Dynamically define tables to write to csv in r

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I am trying to write multiple dataframes to multiple .csv files dynmanically. I have found online how to do the latter part, but not the former (dynamically define the dataframe).

```
# create separate dataframes from each 12 month interval of closed age
for (i in 1:max_age) {assign(paste("closed",i*12,sep=""),
                         mc_masterc[mc_masterc[,7]==i*12,]) 

write.csv(paste("closed",i*12,sep=""),paste("closed",i*12,".csv",sep=""),
               row.names=FALSE)
          }
```

In the code above, the problem is with the first part of the write.csv statement. It will create the .csv file dynamically, but not with the actual content from the table I am trying to specify. What should the first argument of the write.csv statement be? Thank you.

Comment: My advice to you is to _not_ use `assign` here, but rather maintain a list of data frames, with each list entry having some dynamic name.  If you poke around SO, you will find examples of how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of `write.csv` needs to be an R object, not a string. If you don't need the objects in memory you can do it like so:

```
for (i in 1:max_age) {
  df <- mc_masterc[mc_masterc[,7]==i*12,]) 

  write.csv(df,paste("closed",i*12,".csv",sep=""),
               row.names=FALSE)
}
```

and if you need them in memory, you can either do that separately, or use `get` to return an object based on a string. Seperate:

```
for (i in 1:max_age) {
  df <- mc_masterc[mc_masterc[,7]==i*12,]) 

  assign(paste("closed",i*12,sep=""),df)
  write.csv(df,paste("closed",i*12,".csv",sep=""),
               row.names=FALSE)
}
```

With `get`:

```
for (i in 1:max_age) {
  assign(paste("closed",i*12,sep=""), mc_masterc[mc_masterc[,7]==i*12,]) 

  write.csv(get(paste("closed",i*12,sep="")),paste("closed",i*12,".csv",sep=""),
           row.names=FALSE)
}
```